# How to show notification on Android 8+

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-service

In my application i want show notification and for this i used FireBase messaging service.
I write below codes under **android 8** show notification but above of **android 8** not show any notification!
I know for show notification upper than android 8 i should used **ChannelID** and i write codes for this, but not show any notification!

**MyNotificationManager class:**

```
public class MyNotificationManager {

    private Context mCtx;
    private Uri soundUri;
    private static MyNotificationManager mInstance;
    private Intent intent;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private NotificationManager mNotifyMgr;

    public MyNotificationManager(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
    }

    public static synchronized MyNotificationManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MyNotificationManager(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void displayNotification(String title, String body) {

        createNotificationChannel();

        // main initialize
        soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Get General

        intent = new Intent(mCtx, SplashActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        if (mNotifyMgr != null) {
            mNotifyMgr.notify(0, getNotifyBuilder(title, body, pendingIntent).build());
        }

    }

    private NotificationCompat.Builder getNotifyBuilder(String title, String body, PendingIntent pendingIntent) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mCtx, "utp_channel_1")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        return mBuilder;
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "app_channel";
            String description = "app_channel_desc";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("app_channel_id", name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            NotificationManager notificationManager = mCtx.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}
```

**MyFireBaseMessagingService class :**

```
public class MyFireBaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        showNotify(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    }

    private void showNotify(String title, String body) {
        MyNotificationManager myNotificationManager = new MyNotificationManager(getApplicationContext());
        myNotificationManager.displayNotification(title, body);
    }
}
```

**Manifest codes:**

```
</service>
<service android:name=".utility.firebase.MyFireBaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: use same instance of notification manager. You are creating a new one in create channel method

Comment: @VivekMishra, how can i it? can you send to me true code with my above codes? please

Comment: @VivekMishra, i used this code : `mNotifyMgr.createNotificationChannel(channel);` but again not work!

Comment: Are you using same channel id at notification method which you are creating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your FirebaseMessagingService class you are only handling
notification payload and not data payload. If app is in kill state and
you send notification it doesn't call onReceive() method so send title
and message of notification in data payload and generate notification.

Try below code

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        //if messages contains data payload (map of custom key values)
         if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){
            //handle the data message here           
            sendNotification(remoteMessage);
        }

        //if notification payload
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){          
            sendNotification(remoteMessage);
        }
    }


private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
         int notification_id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
         NotificationManager notificationManager = null;
         NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;

         String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
         String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
         String type = remoteMessage.getData().get("type");

         //Set pending intent to builder
         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

         //Notification builder
         if (notificationManager == null){
             notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
         }


        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID);
            if (mChannel == null){
                mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, importance);
                mChannel.setDescription(CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION);
                mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                mChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
                mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }

            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_small)
                    .setContentText(body) //show icon on status bar
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
        }else {
            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_small)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(1002, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

It will handle both Android 8+ and below Android 8+.

Comment: Thanks dear, i used your code but show me very small size of notification :D how can i fix this small size?

Comment: If you want bigger size of notification you have to use custom layout for it

Comment: in your code not show notify title and content! just show app name and icon! how can i show notify title and content?

Comment: setContentTitle() and setContentText is for the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
private void addNotification() {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default", "Channel name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setDescription("Channel description");
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "default")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notiicon)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setContentText("Your text.....");
        builder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
```

Comment: are you here? can you help me?

Comment: @Apptester hii, what issue you get?? i checked this code in  emulator and its working find

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel, really i don't know! but not work me!!!! can you help me?

Comment: @Apptester ,  yes sure. Just copy this function in your app and call this function inside your onCreate(). you will see notification will be there in your statusbar. If there is anything else let me know

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel, do you have TeamViewer? for connect to my PC?

Comment: @Apptester i am at work place, cant do that right now. If you can wait, then will do that after 7pm

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel, i copy above codes into my service! but not show me any notitifcation!

Answer (score 0):

you should also try with this and let me know:

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder1 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this, "my_channel_01").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.buy_gas)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name)).setContentText("Title goes here").setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder1.setAutoCancel(true);


        NotificationManager mNotificationManager1 = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            mBuilder1.setChannelId("my_channel_01");

            CharSequence name = "My New Channel";                   // The user-visible name of the channel.
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("my_channel_01", name, importance); //Create Notification Channel
            channel.setDescription("Channel description");
            mNotificationManager1.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        mNotificationManager1.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), mBuilder1.build());
```

Comment: @Apptester try with this

Comment: @Apptester why you create seperate class MyNotificationManager  for notification. Use this inside MyFireBaseMessagingService itself

Comment: not work me again my friend :( . i copy your code into my service and again not work me